# HTML form needs double click to focus on field

Tags: jquery, html, forms, focus

For some reason one of my forms (I have 2 forms in the same page) is not working properly because I need to double click on each form field in order to be able to enter data.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: Browser? JavaScript? Is there a live demo?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to direct this question at the guys at http://www.doctype.com/.

Comment: You cannot ask for help without providing at least some code or a URL.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/m1e448392

But it doesn't have anything strange on it.

Comment: A live working example of the page is going to help more than anything else. The code you posted in only basic form code, which works fine.

Comment: There is no live example yet, it's under development. I will start from scratch and re-create this page.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, try disabling javascript in your browser to make sure you don't have something causing this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue happening in every browser?

The first thing I'd check is which browsers it's happening in.

Then, make sure your code validates.

Then, strip out each form element, one by one, to see if that isolates where the problem's happening.  That will make a big difference if you can work out where the issue is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This is my guess given the limited info:

```
<form name="form1">
    <label for="input1">
       <input id="input1" type="text" />
    </label>
</form>
<form name="form2">
    <label for="input1">
       <input id="input2" type="text" />
    </label>
</form>
```

So what is happening when you click to enter text in **input2**, it is focusing on **input1** because the **label for=** is pointing to **input1**

The **label for=** on the second input should be **input2**